# Lang's Algebra page 613 equivalent definitions of Flat Module. F3 $\implies$ F1. How?

Tags: category-theory, modules, tensor-products, exact-sequence, functors

We are working in a category of modules and their morphisms.

> **F3.** For every injection $0 \to E' \to E$ the sequence $0 \to F\otimes E' \to F \otimes E$ is exact.

> **F1.** For every exact sqequence $E' \to E \to E''$ the sequence $F\otimes E' \to F \otimes E \to F\otimes E''$ is exact.

**Question.** How does one prove that F3 $\implies$ F1?

The hint in the book says:

> [...] by writing down the kernel and image of the map $E' \to E$ and applying F3.

---

**Attempt.**  Given $E' \xrightarrow{f} E \xrightarrow{g} E''$ we have that if $K = \ker f$ and $I = \text{im f}$, then $0 \to K \to E' \to I \to 0$ is exact.  Applying F3 and the fact that $\otimes$ is right exact gives us that:

$$
0 \to F\otimes K \to F\otimes E' \to F\otimes I \to 0
$$

is exact.  But we can do the same thing for $g$ so that:

$$
0 \to F\otimes K' \to F\otimes E\to F\otimes I' \to 0
$$

But $K' = \ker g = \text{im } f = I$.  We can't simply glue at $F\otimes I$ and compose the two maps - doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I think I see now.  $I \subset E$ so that $F\otimes I$ is a submodule of $F \otimes E$ so we can view $F\otimes f$ as a map from $F \otimes E'$ into $F\otimes E$ and we're done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is really a comment that won't fit as a comment.

You've probably solved this problem already, but I want to show you a way to draw diagrams so as to make it super easy to visualise how the various morphisms fit together. Personally, I find these diagrams extremely helpful when constructing these kinds of proofs - without them, I feel a bit lost.

I'll explain the approach in the context of the $F \otimes .$ functor (flat modules), but idea is also applicable to the $\text{Hom}(P,.)$ functor (projective modules) and to the $\text{Hom}(.,I)$ functor (injective modules).

**Original diagram**

We start with the diagram below.

[image: original]

This is a *commutative* diagram. Both triangles commute.

All three of the diagonal arrow sequences (in black) are *exact* sequences.

The horizontal arrow sequence (in blue) is also an *exact* sequence.

**Tensoring with $F$ (when $F$ is not necessarily flat)**

Suppose $F$ is some module, not necessarily flat. If we apply the $F \otimes .$ functor to our diagram, then we get a new diagram, as shown below.

[image: tensored]

This too is a commutative diagram - both triangles commute.

The three diagonal arrow sequences (in black) are exact, but notice that a couple of $0 \to .$ arrows from the the original diagram have disappeared. This is because the $F \otimes \text{Im}(f) \to F \otimes E$ and $F \otimes \text{Im}(g) \to F \otimes E''$ morphisms are not necessarily injective.

The horizontal arrow sequence (in blue) is *not* necessarily exact. The most we can say about the horizontal arrow sequence is that
$$ \text{Im}(1 \otimes f) \subset \text{Ker}(1 \otimes g).$$
Please verify this claim using the diagram. It's a simple exercise in  "diagram-chasing".

**Tensoring with a flat $F$**

So how are things different when $F$ is flat? When $F$ is flat, then the diagram looks like this.

[image: tensored flat]

The $0 \to .$ arrows have been restored, because the $F \otimes \text{Im}(f) \to F \otimes E$ and $F \otimes \text{Im}(g) \to F \otimes E''$ morphisms *are* injective, since $F$ is flat.

What's especially important is that the $F \otimes \text{Im}(g) \to F \otimes E''$ morphism is injective. This means that any element in the kernel of the $F \otimes E \to F \otimes E''$ morphism is also in the kernel of the $F \otimes E \to F \otimes \text{Im}(g)$ morphism. If you finish off this "diagram-chasing" argument, you should be able to deduce that
$$ \text{Ker}(1 \otimes g) \subset \text{Im}(1 \otimes f).$$

Thus, the horizontal arrow sequence (in blue) *is* an exact sequence.

**Summary**

A nice way to summarise our findings is:

- In general, tensoring an exact sequence by some module $F$ does not necessarily produce an exact sequence (though it does produce a chain complex).
- But if $F$ is flat, then we *do* produce an exact sequence.

Comment: This is really great.  I love commutative diagrams!

Comment: Me too! I find them quite satisfying.

Comment: Do you know about https://q.uiver.app?

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for. Can't believe I drew this in excalidraw.